Windows Server блокирует порт
Написал вот такой незатейливый код для проверки возможности подключения к определённому порту на сервере:
//#define ROLE_SERVER

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace TestPortAccess {

    internal class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            const string ipAddress = "{IP}";
            const int port = 8443;

#if ROLE_SERVER

            var listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add($"https://+:{port}/");
            listener.Start();

            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine("Wait for context...");
                var httpContext = listener.GetContext();
                Console.WriteLine("Context received!");

                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                httpContext.Response.Close();
            }
#else

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            try {
                var response = client.PostAsync($"https://{ipAddress}:{port}/", new StringContent("Hello"))
                    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
#endif
        }
    }
}

Брандмауэр на клиенте и на сервере выключен, Windows Defender тоже, никакого другого ПО на сервере не работает. Однако при выполнении запроса со стороны клиенты возникает исключение:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Произошла ошибка при отправке
запроса. ---> System.Net.WebException: Базовое соединение закрыто:
Непредвиденная ошибка при передаче. ---> System.IO.IOException: Не
удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Удаленный хост
принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: ...

В чём может быть проблема? Что может блокировать доступ к порту и какие есть способы в этом разобраться?
OS: Windows Server 2019
Target .NET Framework: 4.5.2
PS: К порту привязан самоподписанный SSL-сертификат, добавленный в хранилище сертификатов сервера.

А если с браузера попытаться? А GET запросы работают? А по HTTP работает? Сервер на дотнете версии дедушек - это обязательное требование? Я даже не уверен, что он TLS 1.2 поддерживает и впринципе способен прожевать все возможные сертификаты.

GET запросы так же не работают. В браузере ошибка ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. По HTTP работает. Портировал под .NET Core 8.0 - ситуация аналогичная.

Вопрос как звучит? "Windows Server блокирует порт", на раз по HTTP работает, значит не блокирует, верно? Значит не работает по TLS и порты не при чём, так? Значит надо решать, что с сертификатами, и почему они не работают. В .NET 8 код, использующий ServicePointManager не подходит, так как там через SocketsHttpHandler всё работает. Но проблема скорее всего именно на стороне сервера, если даже браузером подключиться не получается. Блокировки нет, есть проблема с сертификатами, а конкретнее, они просто не подцепились.

И стоит ли изобретать велосипед, если можно просто создать проект ASP.NET Core, где HTTP стек готовый и рабочий.

"Значит не работает по TLS и порты не при чём, так?" - Получается что так. "есть проблема с сертификатами, а конкретнее, они просто не подцепились" - Я проверял следующим образом: netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8443 показывает какой сертификат привязан к порту, сертификат с таким же thumbprint существует в хранилище сертификатов компьютера. Разве не достаточно условий выполняется?

@aepot Такой вывод команды: https://pastebin.com/bDcXHBa9

К сожалению, дальше у меня эеспертизы нет. Возможно кто-то другой поможет. Переформулируйте вопрос, так как он не про блокировку портов.

Кажется это решило мою проблему: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091100/8110665. Потестирую ещё и оформлю ответ если всё хорошо.
